# How to trace native crash

Tags: android

Got following crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup.resetCancelNextUpFlag(ViewGroup.java:2213)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2159)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2161)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2139)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1476)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2087)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7535)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3415)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3347)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4456)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4434)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4538)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

As you can see it has no lines mentioning my application, so how to deal with these? Building my app for min api level 8.

I do not have the steps to reproduce this error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use android log api to put logs inside the native code to check where it stops working.

to perform trace add headers to your C/C++ files.

```
  #include <android/log.h>
  #define  LOG_TAG    "NDK"
  #define  NLOG(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
```

In Android.mk file make sure you add following flag in your module to enable logging

```
  LOCAL_LDLIBS :=-llog
```

and then you can use it like below code

```
  NLOG("bitmap width %d",imagewidth);
```

Comment: Got this trace with crash reporting tool, don't know how to reproduce steps. And besides logging whole application to find a crash sounds pretty painful.

Comment: just put the logs at major functions in your native source and try to reproduce the scenario you will get hint from where crash is coming.if you did that before you might get logs in this type of situation.